# pytest.skip within pytest_generate_tests skips all test functions in module instead of specific tests

Tags: python, pytest

I'm parameterizing pytest tests with variables defined in an external YAML file using the pytest_generate_tests hook.  The name of the variable file is specified on the pytest command line (--params_file).  Only some of the test functions within a module are parameterized and require the variables in this file. Thus, the command line option defining the variables is an optional argument.  If the optional argument is omitted from the command line, then I want pytest to just "skip" those test functions which need the external parameterized variables and just run the "other" tests which are not parameterized.  The problem is, if the command line option is omitted, pytest is skipping ALL of the test functions, not just the test functions that require the parameters.

Here is the test module file:

```
def test_network_validate_1(logger, device_connections,):

  ### Test code omitted.....


def test_lsp_throttle_timers(params_file, logger, device_connections):

  ### Test code omitted.....

def test_network_validate_2(logger, device_connections,):

  ### Test code omitted.....
```

pytest_generate_tests hook in conftest.py:

```
# Note, I tried scope at function level as well but that did not help
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def params_file(request):
    pass

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
  
    ### Get Pytest rootdir
    rootdir = metafunc.config.rootdir

    print(f"*********** Test Function: {metafunc.function.__name__}")

    if "params_file" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        print("*********** Hello Silver ****************")
        if metafunc.config.getoption("--params_file"):

            #################################################################
            # Params file now located as a separate command line argument for
            # greater flexibility
            #################################################################
            params_file = metafunc.config.getoption("--params_file")
            params_doc = dnet_generic.open_yaml_file(Path(rootdir, params_file),
                                                    loader_type=yaml.Loader)

            test_module = metafunc.module.__name__
            test_function = metafunc.function.__name__
            names,values = dnet_generic.get_test_parameters(test_module,
                                                            test_function,
                                                            params_doc,)

            metafunc.parametrize(names, values )
        else:
            pytest.skip("This test requires the params_file argument")
```

When the params_file option is present, everything works fine:

```
pytest isis/test_isis_lsp_throttle.py --testinfo topoA_r28.yml --ulog -s --params_file common/topoA_params.yml  --collect-only
===================================================================================== test session starts =====================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.4, pytest-3.7.0, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0
rootdir: /home/as2863/pythonProjects/p1-automation, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: csv-2.0.1, check-0.3.5, pylama-7.6.6, dependency-0.4.0, instafail-0.4.0, ordering-0.6, repeat-0.7.0, reportportal-5.0.3
collecting 0 items                                                                                                                                                                            *********** Test Function: test_network_validate_1
*********** Test Function: test_lsp_throttle_timers
*********** Test Function: test_network_validate_2
collected 3 items
<Package '/home/as2863/pythonProjects/p1-automation/isis'>
  <Module 'test_isis_lsp_throttle.py'>
    <Function 'test_network_validate_1'>
    <Function 'test_lsp_throttle_timers'>
    <Function 'test_network_validate_2'>

================================================================================ no tests ran in 0.02 seconds =================================================================================
```

When the params_file option is ommitted, you can see that no tests are run and the print statement shows it does not even try to run pytest_generate_tests on "test_network_validate_2"

```
pytest isis/test_isis_lsp_throttle.py --testinfo topoA_r28.yml --ulog -s  --collect-only                         ===================================================================================== test session starts =====================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.4, pytest-3.7.0, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0
rootdir: /home/as2863/pythonProjects/p1-automation, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: csv-2.0.1, check-0.3.5, pylama-7.6.6, dependency-0.4.0, instafail-0.4.0, ordering-0.6, repeat-0.7.0, reportportal-5.0.3
collecting 0 items

*********** Test Function: test_network_validate_1
*********** Test Function: test_lsp_throttle_timers
*********** Hello Silver ****************
collected 0 items / 1 skipped

================================================================================== 1 skipped in 0.11 seconds ==================================================================================
```

Comment: That's strange - so basically if you have an empty `pytest_generate_tests` no tests will be generated?

Comment: correct. no tests are generated

Comment: Hm - what if you remove `pytest_generate_tests` completely? That should have the same effect as an empty one. If that still behaves the same, there must be something else wrong...

Comment: If I completely comment out pytest_generate_tests (in conftest.py), then all 3 tests are collected; with or without the --params_file command line argument.

Comment: So, to make sure: if you just write `def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc): pass` no tests are collected? That is very strange...

Comment: If I do def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc): pass,  then all 3 tests are generated, with or without the --params_file argument

Comment: Hm, that is expected behavior... I still have no idea. Are you sure you are showing the full content of `pytest_generate_tests`? Because in the shown code it does nothing but print something, which is not much different from just writing `pass`. I would try to remove the whole if condition, and if that still works, parts of it, until you find the responsible code - from looking at the code I see nothing that should cause that behavior.

Comment: What appears to be happening is when one of the three tests (the 2nd one) hits the pytest.skip() method, pytest is bailing out.  It's as if pytest.skip() is working at the module scope instead of the function scope???  yes, I am showing the full content of pytest_generate_tests.  I was using an older version of pytest but upgraded to pytest 6.1.2 and still same behavior.

Comment: You are right - I learned something new, too. I put a possible solution into an answer, pease check.

Answer (score 5):

As has been found in the discussion in the comments, you cannot use `pytest.skip` in `pytest_generate_tests`, because it will work on module scope. To skip the concrete test, you can do something like this:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def skip_test():
    pytest.skip('Some reason')

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "params_file" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        if metafunc.config.getoption("--params_file"):
            ...
            metafunc.parametrize(names, values )
        else:
            metafunc.fixturenames.insert(0, 'skip_test')
```

E.g. you introduce a fixture that will skip the concrete test, and add this fixture to the test. Make sure to insert it as the first fixture, so no other fixtures will be executed.

Comment: That did the trick!  Excellent solution.  I was not even aware you could dynamically insert a fixture into a test function with metafunc.fixturenames.insert()

Comment: This answer may not be very robust. According to https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/4017, the Pytest authors aren't shy about this breaking under certain scenarios, and suggest you have an `autouse` fixture you parameterize with `indirect`.

Answer (score 0):

While MrBean Bremen's answer may work, [according to the pytest authors](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/4017) dynamically altering the fixture list is not something they really want to support. This approach, however, is a bit more supported.

```py
# This is "auto used", but doesn't always skip the test unless the test parameters require it
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def skip_test(request):
    # For some reason this is only conditionally set if a param is passed
    # https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/791b51d0faea365aa9474bb83f9cd964fe265c21/src/_pytest/fixtures.py#L762
    if not hasattr(request, 'param'):
        return

    pytest.skip(f"Test skipped: {request.param}")
```

And in your test module:

```py
def _add_flag_parameter(metafunc: pytest.Metafunc, name: str):
    if name not in metafunc.fixturenames:
        return

    flag_value = metafunc.config.getoption(name)
    if flag_value:
        metafunc.parametrize(name, [flag_value])
    else:
        metafunc.parametrize("skip_test", ["Missing flag '{name}'"], indirect=True)

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc: pytest.Metafunc):
    _add_flag_parameter(metafunc, "params_file")
```